# Example of $\mu(I)=\mu(I/I^2)+1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, finitely-generated

Let $I$ be a finitely generated ideal of a commutative ring $R$ (with unity 1). Let $\mu(S)$ denotes the cardinality of minimal generating set of $S$. It can be shown (via determinant trick) that 
$$\mu(I/I^2)\le \mu(I) \le \mu(I/I^2)+1$$

> What I wish to see is few examples where $\mu(I)=\mu(I/I^2)+1$.

I was thinking about a simple case where $I$ is a non principal ideal of Noetherian ring but $I/I^2$ is cyclic as an $R/I$ module. But didn't find any. Any help / suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just take $I$ to be a non-principal prime ideal in a Dedekind domain.

As a concrete example, how about $R=\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-6}]$ and
$I=\left<2,\sqrt{-6}\right>$?

Comment: I can see that your specific example works. However, I am curious about your assertion that any non-principal prime ideal in a Dedekind domain would work. I don't really know about Dedekind domain. So, I was wondering how does it works?

Answer (score 4):

If $I$ is generated by a (nonzero) idempotent, then $I^2=I$, so $\mu(I)=1$ but $\mu(I/I^2)=0$.  For an explicit example, you could take $R=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $I$ to be the ideal generated by $(1,0)$.